# como ejecutar un script de Python desde Wordpress

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.
Soy bastante nuevo con Python y por ahora solo estoy dando mis primeros pasos haciendo web scrappers y herramientas de red.

El problema:
Tengo un web scrapper que funciona de maravillas desde el Idle. Ahora bien, tengo que usarlo desde Wordpress.

Necesito que el usuario que visite mi sitio web ingrese el ASIN o el ISBN en una caja de busqueda y que esta busqueda la ejecute MI script y NO el motor propio de WP.
Como dije soy nuevo en esto y me encuebtro con que:

No se como editar, si se pudiera, el motor de busqueda del WP para que "apunte" a mi script.

No se si deberia crear una caja de busqueda propia en python que tome el input del user y directamente ejecute el web.scrapper e insertar TODO ese modulo en WP; si es asi, como se inserta el script?

SI las dos anteriores no son viables, se puede "llamar" al script de python desde WP? Como?

Cualquier otra solucion es bienvenida, quizas estoy pensando la respuesta de la forma equivocada.

Gracias

Comment: Tu script tendría que estar ejecutándose en un servidor capaz de ejecutar python (diferente del que aloja el wordpress). Deberías crear una api rest para tu servicio, para lo que te puede servir `flask`. Entonces podrías extender Wordpress con un plugin para que conecte con el servidor flask y haga las peticiones apropiadas. Esta parte tendría que hacerse en PHP, que es el lenguaje usado por wordpress. No es para nada trivial. Ya puestos a alojar en otro servidor la parte python, podrías prescindir de la parte wordpress y dejar que python te de el resultado en html (usando jinja).

Comment: Si la máquina donde está instalado wordpress también tiene instalado python y los módulos necesarios, podría ser más sencillo. Basta usar `exec()` desde el PHP para ejecutar cualquier comando externo (que podría ser `python`). Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405788/1264820) (en inglés).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias  abulafia, estaba leyendo la respuesta en Ingles. Si , aparentemente no es nada facil. Me parece mas apropiado tratar de "traducir" el webscrapper de python a php y correrlo asi desde WP. Desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo